# Eclipse giving error when adding MySql jdbc driver

Tags: mysql, eclipse

I am getting below exception

```
A driver already exists with that name. Please provide a unique driver name.
```

[image]

Anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 11):

Please follow: http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/jdbc.html

A driver already exists with that name. Please provide a unique driver name.
...until you remove the workspace's internal (but wrong) knowledge of that driver. (This process is more complicated than for a "simple" User Library.)

To remove a driver definition so that you can re-add it from scratch to match its actual location on disk:

Close the Build Path dialog.

Open workspace preferences (menu Window -> Preferences).

Expand Data Management by clicking its triangle.

Example Connectivity by clicking its triangle.

Click Driver Definitions.

Click on the offending definition, for the example in this article it would be "MySQL JDBC Driver | MySQL | 5.1" and then click Remove.

Dismiss the preferences dialog by clicking OK.

Return to Build Path in the project for which you need the MySQL JDBC driver and follow the steps to set up a new driver above.

If you experience trouble reaching Build Path, getting a weird error, bounce Eclipse (and return to the same workspace and project). You'll almost surely find that the problem has cleared and you can successfully follow the steps above again.

Answer (score -1):

To reftify this error you need to change the Default Name of the driver (means change the Driver Name) Clear the doubt:
[image: CLear the doubt]