# mySQL: Connection with Eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jar

I have a lots of problem with the connection between eclipse EE and mySQL. I need to create a web application so I need a DB. I downloaded mySQL ( and mySQL workbench ).

I go to connect eclipse to DB but I can't do it.

This is the sequence that I do:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Please give me some information, I need to solve this . Thanks you guys.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to complete the [tour] and read [ask] before asking a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624852/eclipse-giving-error-when-adding-mysql-jdbc-driver

Comment: he uses Hibernate

Comment: Setting up a JDBC connection in eclipse should be the same, no matter which framework you are going to use in your project. Did you encounter a problem following the guidelines in the other question?

Comment: My problem is not about driver definition, I can't connect Eclipse to DB because I have a ping error

Comment: I follow this guide, but it is not my problem. I have deleted the driver and installed a new one like the guide says, but when I go to put my information ( root, password.. ) like the photos I have the same ping error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So setting up a JDBC connection in Eclipse can be much easier than your approach. You can instead, try this:

1. Right click on your Java class in the Package Explorer in the Eclipse workspace.
2. Go down the list that appears until you find Build Path and click Add External Archives.
3. Find the jar file called mysql-connector-java-*version number*.jar and open it. This should connect your JDBC to Eclipse!

Hope this helps!